# Where can I find publicly available data on American dietary habits and food intake during the Great Depression?

Tags: medical, historical, food

I'm looking for detailed data on American dietary habits during during the Great Depression and WWII era, specifically 1930 - 1945. Were there any surveys that collected detailed information, at a household level (ideally with demographic characteristics too) about the foods and other items that Americans consumed?